# Custom icon not displaying in android

Tags: android

I have created an icon in eclipse for my app but when I run the app the icon changes to the android icon in the first page of my app but the other screens display the icon perfectly.I want to know why does it change to the android icon on the first page.

Here is the xml file of the first page.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@color/LightGrey">


     <EditText
         android:id="@+id/password"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/username"
         android:layout_below="@+id/username"
         android:layout_marginTop="77dp"
         android:ems="10"
         android:hint="@string/password"
         android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="96dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/username"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/password"
        android:layout_below="@+id/password"
        android:layout_marginTop="63dp"
        android:background="#808080"
        android:text="@string/login"
        android:typeface="serif" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Where is it supposed to be displayed? Nothing in your current code to display it...

Comment: Are you 100% sure you're referencing the correct ID for the drawable as well as closing and opening <> correctly?

Comment: please post the onCreate() method of both activities.

Comment: Thanks a lot . The icon is now displayed on the first screen. I had to remove the following code from the first xml file       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"

Answer (score 1):

Remember to change the "android icon" for your new icon insinde all your drawable folders:

```
drawable-hdpi
drawable-ldpi
drawable-mdpi
drawable-xdpi
```

(inside the .xml that you are showing there´s no reference of an image)

More info: [**Supporting Multiple Screens**](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: ok check your drawable folders if you replaced the original icon for the new one.